# UIStackView: Aspect fill image squashed issue

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I have 4 images inside a `UIStackView` which is constrained 20pts from top, right, bottom, left.

4 images are set to `Aspect Fit` and the `UIStackView` settings are set to: Fill Equally, and Spacing of 20.

When I come to view this on an iPhone 8 upwards the layout works. When viewing on an iPhone SE layout I get squashing of the images as below.

Shouldn't the fact that Aspect Fit has been set solve this issue and scale the image down accordingly?

[image: Initial constraint values]

[image: View showing on smaller devices]

Thanks

Comment: Where is the purple circle coming from? Is that background colour? Is that an image? Can you share the image?

Comment: The circle is a pdf image, I've also tried using a background color.\

Comment: Can you show the code where you put the image in. You are missing something but it is hard to know what as we have so little information to go on.

Comment: Image is added using interface Builder, unless you want the entire XML storyboard structure?

Comment: Can you try using a PNG image instead of PDF? I wonder if the PDF does not contain the correct intrinsic size?

Comment: Can you share the PDF image? Would be useful to give it a try myself to see what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an aspect ratio constraint to each image and set it to 1:1. This should make the images have the same height and width, no matter the width of the screen.

I agree however, that using "aspect fit" should work. Are these regular images stored in your app bundle, or are you creating them with code or something similar?

Comment: I've tried both approaches, the current is a pdf image

Comment: What sizes are the UIImageViews when you run your app? If you click the "Debug view hierarchy" in XCode while running the app, what constraints do you have, and what are their values?

Comment: Adding in the ratio suggestion along with setting the content hugging to 749 and a trailing constraint worked on all screen sizes. I'll have to remove the constraint on SE layouts but thats a minor niggle. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user7684436 you shouldn't have to change constraints or specific devices at all. You have found a workaround for the problem here... you haven't fixed it.

Comment: Well I know I shouldn't but with Xcode being the great piece of software it is - I had to.